# Redshift Correlated Subquery Pattern Not Supported

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

Let me preface by saying that I know this is not a particularly efficient or elegant piece of code. I am querying from a temp table called INSIDE made like so:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE INSIDE (CONNECT_DATE DATE, DAILY_CONNECTIONS INT);`
```

I'm then attempting to run the following query on INSIDE in an attempt to test a model I've been working on.

```
SELECT *
, q5.DAN_PREDICTION - q5.LINEAR_PREDICTION AS PREDICTION_COMPARISON
, q5.DAN_PREDICTION - q5.ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT AS DAN_VARIANCE
, q5.LINEAR_PREDICTION - q5.ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT AS LINEAR_VARIANCE
FROM (SELECT *
  , q4.mtd + q4.last_yr_remainder + q4.run_rate * q4.days_remaining AS DAN_PREDICTION
  , q4.mtd + q4.curr_yr_7_day * days_remaining AS LINEAR_PREDICTION
    FROM(
SELECT 
       *
      , q3.curr_yr_7_day - q3.last_yr_7_day AS RUN_RATE
      FROM(
        SELECT 
          CONNECT_DATE
        , DAILY_CONNECTIONS 
        , (cur_yr_1_prev + cur_yr_2_prev + cur_yr_3_prev + cur_yr_4_prev + cur_yr_5_prev + cur_yr_6_prev + cur_yr_7_prev)/7 AS CURR_YR_7_DAY
        , (last_yr_1_prev + last_yr_2_prev + last_yr_3_prev + last_yr_4_prev + last_yr_5_prev + last_yr_6_prev + last_yr_7_prev)/7 AS LAST_YR_7_DAY
        , (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ins.DAILY_CONNECTIONS), 0) 
            FROM INSIDE ins 
            WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, ins.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH, q2.CONNECT_DATE) 
            AND DATEPART(YEAR, ins.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, q2.CONNECT_DATE)
            AND ins.CONNECT_DATE <= q2.CONNECT_DATE) AS MTD
        , (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ins.DAILY_CONNECTIONS), 0) 
            FROM INSIDE ins 
            WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, ins.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH, q2.CONNECT_DATE) 
            AND DATEPART(YEAR, ins.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, q2.CONNECT_DATE)-1
            AND ins.CONNECT_DATE > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, q2.CONNECT_DATE)) AS LAST_YR_REMAINDER
        , (SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(DAY, last_day(CONNECT_DATE)) 
            FROM INSIDE 
            WHERE CONNECT_DATE = q2.CONNECT_DATE)-DATEPART(DAY, q2.CONNECT_DATE) DAYS_REMAINING
        , (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ins.DAILY_CONNECTIONS), 0) 
            FROM INSIDE ins 
            WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, ins.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH, q2.CONNECT_DATE)
            AND DATEPART(YEAR, ins.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, q2.CONNECT_DATE)) AS ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT
        FROM
          (SELECT 
            q1.CONNECT_DATE CONNECT_DATE
          , q1.DAILY_CONNECTIONS DAILY_CONNECTIONS
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-1,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_1_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-2,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_2_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-3,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_3_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-4,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_4_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-5,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_5_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-6,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_6_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-7,q1.connect_date)), 0) CUR_YR_7_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-1,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_1_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-2,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_2_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-3,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_3_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-4,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_4_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-5,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_5_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-6,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_6_PREV
          , ISNULL((SELECT DAILY_CONNECTIONS FROM INSIDE WHERE CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1,(DATEADD(DAY,-7,q1.connect_date)))), 0) LAST_YR_7_PREV
          FROM INSIDE q1 ORDER BY q1.CONNECT_DATE
        ) q2 ORDER BY q2.connect_date
      ) q3  
    ) q4 
  ) q5
```

Running the inner q1 query seems to work just fine; the problem starts when I run the subqueries in q2. Running any more than one of them (MTD, LAST_YR_REMAINDER, etc) at a time produces the following error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

I've been reviewing the documentation for unsupported subquery types in Redshift and don't understand which rule these are breaking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you have seen http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html It is likely that some pattern is being hit that is not available. I think this could be rewritten though in a different and perhaps better way. please can you update your question to include some sample data, the "logic" of what you are doing and the expected output?

Comment: `connect_date daily_connections:
2016-05-20 867`

I calculate a year over year run-rate by finding the difference between the average number of connections over the past seven days from a date and the seven day average of the past year. I then add the number of connections for the month on the date in question to the remainder of the connections for the same month last year, plus the run rate multiplied by the number of days left in the month from the connect date. The final step (q5) is just comparing that result to a few things.

Comment: I will take a look later - please update your question with the text you have in your comment. reason :its important to make the question as full as possible for others to follow without having to go through comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many inline subqueries. Try using common table expressions (`CTE`) to decompose the logic in a way that Redshift can run efficiently.

Most of your inline subqueries can be rewritten as an aggregate over a Cartesian product.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT i1.CONNECT_DATE       CONNECT_DATE
          ,i1.DAILY_CONNECTIONS  DAILY_CONNECTIONS
           -- Sub-selects converted to an aggregate over a sparse matrix
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -1, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_1_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -2, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_2_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -3, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_3_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -4, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_4_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -5, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_5_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -6, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_6_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(DAY,  -7, i1.connect_date)                    THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) CUR_YR_7_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-1, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_1_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-2, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_2_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-3, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_3_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-4, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_4_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-5, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_5_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-6, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_6_PREV
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-7, i1.connect_date))) THEN DAILY_CONNECTIONS ELSE NULL END) LAST_YR_7_PREV
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, i2.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH, i1.CONNECT_DATE) 
                     AND DATEPART(YEAR, i2.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, i1.CONNECT_DATE) 
                     AND i2.CONNECT_DATE <= i1.CONNECT_DATE
                    THEN i2.DAILY_CONNECTIONS 
               ELSE NULL END)   AS MTD
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, i2.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH, i1.CONNECT_DATE) 
                     AND DATEPART(YEAR, i2.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, i1.CONNECT_DATE)-1
                     AND i2.CONNECT_DATE > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, i1.CONNECT_DATE)
                    THEN i2.DAILY_CONNECTIONS 
               ELSE NULL END)   AS LAST_YR_REMAINDER
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN i2.CONNECT_DATE = i1.CONNECT_DATE-DATEPART(DAY, i1.CONNECT_DATE) 
                    THEN DATEPART(DAY, last_day(CONNECT_DATE)) 
               ELSE NULL END)   AS DAYS_REMAINING
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, i2.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH, i1.CONNECT_DATE)
                     AND DATEPART(YEAR, i2.CONNECT_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, i1.CONNECT_DATE)
                    THEN i2.DAILY_CONNECTIONS
               ELSE NULL END)   AS ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT
    FROM       INSIDE i1
    -- Create an intentional cartesian product
    CROSS JOIN INSIDE i2
    /*  Consider limiting the cartesian to a specific overlap range. E.g.
    WHERE i2.CONNECT_DATE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, (DATEADD(DAY,-7, i1.connect_date)))
    */
    -- Use group by to collapse the cartesian back to the original size
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 1
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT CONNECT_DATE
         , DAILY_CONNECTIONS 
         , (cur_yr_1_prev + cur_yr_2_prev + cur_yr_3_prev + cur_yr_4_prev + cur_yr_5_prev + cur_yr_6_prev + cur_yr_7_prev)/7 AS CURR_YR_7_DAY
         , (last_yr_1_prev + last_yr_2_prev + last_yr_3_prev + last_yr_4_prev + last_yr_5_prev + last_yr_6_prev + last_yr_7_prev)/7 AS LAST_YR_7_DAY
         , MTD, LAST_YR_REMAINDER, DAYS_REMAINING, ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT
    FROM cte1
    ORDER BY connect_date
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT *, curr_yr_7_day - last_yr_7_day AS RUN_RATE
    FROM cte2  
), cte4 AS (
    SELECT *
          , mtd + last_yr_remainder + run_rate * days_remaining AS DAN_PREDICTION
          , mtd + curr_yr_7_day * days_remaining AS LINEAR_PREDICTION
    FROM cte3
)
SELECT *
     , DAN_PREDICTION - LINEAR_PREDICTION AS PREDICTION_COMPARISON
     , DAN_PREDICTION - ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT AS DAN_VARIANCE
     , LINEAR_PREDICTION - ACTUAL_MONTH_END_AMOUNT AS LINEAR_VARIANCE
FROM cte4
```

Comment: I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66021321/invalid-operation-this-type-of-correlated-subquery-pattern-is-not-supported-due) where I am using CTE but it is giving me an error as correlated subquery. I wanted to see if you can help me out.

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide an example. Then ping here and I will have a look. :D